# Finding angular momentum about the center of mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, vectors

If we have a couple of particles of an equal, unknown mass:

$$r_{+} = (c + e^{-Bt} \cos({\theta}))\textbf{x} + (d + e^{-Bt} \sin({\theta}))\textbf{y}$$

$$r_{-} = (c - e^{-Bt} \cos({\theta}))\textbf{x} + (d - e^{-Bt} \sin({\theta}))\textbf{y}$$

where $c$, $d$, $B$ are positive constants and $\theta$ is a function of $t$.

How do we find the angular momentum about the center of mass? I get $(0, 0)$ and if it is constant, how do we find $\theta$ and the system's kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of mass is not $(0, 0)$. If you take the average of the two positions, you will get $(c, d)$.

The angular momentum $\vec L$ is $\vec r \times \vec p$. With mass $m$, this will be:
$$ \vec L = m \vec r \times \vec v $$

$\vec v_\pm$ is just $\dot{\vec r}_\pm = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \vec r_\pm$. So you have to to a time differentiation of your positions $\vec r_\pm$.

But first of all, you need to get the center of the coordinate system to the center of mass. You do this by subtracting the center of mass from both your positions. You should find that the $c+$ and $d+$ is removed.

Then you can calculate the velocity and then compute the cross product.

Comment: Yeah, I meant I got (0,0) for the angular momentum.

Comment: is the $r$ arrow term just the difference between the two $\pm$ vectors? How about kinetic energy and finding $\theta$?

Comment: No, you have to separately calculate the angular momentum for each particle (using $r_+$ and $r_-$), then add them. To get the kinetic energy, just take $ L^2 / (2I)$.

Comment: Thank you, what is $I$? I think I may use different notation. How does the fact it's constant mean you can find $\theta$?

Comment: $I$ is the moment of inertia. Sometimes also $J$ or $\Theta$. I assume that your $\theta$ is an angle. If it was the moment of intertia, that would be surprising. I thought $\theta(t)$ was a given in your problem? If not, you can at least write down $\vec L$ as a function of $\theta$. The arrow means the following: $\vec r = r_x \mathbf x + r_y \mathbf y$. It just means that $r$ has a magnitude and direction, that it is not a plain number.

Comment: Yeah it is given in the problem as a function of t. How does a constant angular momentum mean you can find $\theta$, though?

Comment: Your system is like a barbell that is rotating. Actually, we only know its rotation angle $\theta(t)$. Since I assume that I can do a time differentiation and get the angular velocity $\omega(t) = \dot\theta(t)$, I can compute $\vec L$ and the energy $E$. But since I needed to know $\theta$, I cannot compute it. Trying to compute $\theta$ does not make sense. You have $\theta(t)$ given. If you did not, and only $L$ or $E$, then it would be like asking: “It is going that fast. Where is it now?” You cannot answer.

Comment: Ah I think the confusion may be that I need to find $\theta$ and the kinetic energy as a function of t.

Comment: You need to find out what is given, what depends on the time and what $\theta$ is supposed to mean in your problem. Before you do that, we will not get any further.

Comment: I need to find $\theta(t)$ and the kinetic energy of the system as a function of t after taking the angular momentum to be constant. Everything else is given in the original question.

Comment: Now we are talking. Here is your roadmap: Express $L$ in terms of $t$ and $\dot \theta(t)$. How to do this should be written about. Then you want that $L$ is a constant. Solve the differential equation for $\theta(t)$. Since the momentum is constant and the distance between the masses is shrinking, the speed will go up. You will end up with some polynom for $\theta(t)$, I think.

Comment: Actually, I got something that wasn't 0 this time. Something in terms of $me^{-2Bt}$ but it's not a vector and angular momentum should be a vector?

Comment: You are just looking in 2D here. So angular momentum will be just a number. Angular momentum will be directed in $\mathbf z$-direction, which you did not introduce yet. But since $\mathbf x \times \mathbf y = \mathbf z$, you will get that with the right-hand-rule. $\vec L = m \vec r \times \vec v$. So angular momentum is perpendicular to both the separation as well as to the velocity.

Comment: Well I got the angular momentum in terms of exponentials ($2me^{-Bt} \dot\theta(t)$, so my solution for $\theta$ is in terms of exponentials as well. Found by just rearranging and integrating. This might disagree with what you said, and I'm sure you're more likely to be right!

Comment: Sounds like you did it right. Rearranging and integrating is what I would have done as well.